# -AppleScript- Trying to run 3 installers one at a time

Tags: applescript

I am new in apple script and I made a simple apple script where it will need to run a couple of installers. Currently here is the process.

1. Copies the Installer files from a Windows host to the Mac Desktop
2. I just simply open the installers using a do shell script open command.

do shell script "open ~/Desktop/installer1.pkg"
do shell script "open ~/Desktop/installer2.pkg"

The problem now is only the first one runs and it skips the 2nd installer. Is there a way for me force the 2nd installer to run after the 1st one?
I also set another pop up that requires user input after the installion is done (supposedly) but the pop up window shows up along with the Installer window. Is there a way for me to delay it after all the installations are done?

Comment: How is the script running the installers?

Comment: The script copies the installer to the Mac desktop from a windows host then I run the installer from there using "do shell script open ~/Desktop/installer.pkg"

Comment: The script should wait until a `do shell script` statement is done.  My question was about how these different installers are being run.  You might consider editing your question to provide more detail.

Comment: I edited my question hope it is more clear now.

Comment: A `do shell script` to just open something will return when it does that.  Those packages are installed by the system's Installer.app and will take a variable amount of time depending on what they are installing and how the user interacts with the dialogs.  You could use System Events to periodically check if the app is still in the list of processes, but a better approach would probably be to check that whatever is supposed to be installed was actually installed.